# ArchUnit rule to test @Service only depends on @Repository in own package?

Tags: archunit

I'd like to write an ArchUnit rule that validates that a service class (Annoted by the `@Service` Spring annotation) will only use a repository from its own package, not from other packages.

I currently have:

```
noClasses().that()
  .areAnnotatedWith(Service.class)
  .should()
  .dependOnClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(Repository.class)
  .orShould().dependOnClassesThat().haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Repository")
```

Which is not good as it does not allow any dependency to a Repository at all.

Alternatively, I could do:

```
noClasses().that()
  .resideInAPackage("com.company.backend.user")
  .and()
  .areAnnotatedWith(Service.class)
  .should()
  .dependOnClassesThat(resideOutsideOfPackage("com.company.backend.user").and(annotatedWith(Repository.class)))
  .orShould().dependOnClassesThat(have(resideOutsideOfPackage("com.company.backend.user").and(simpleNameEndingWith("Repository"))))
  .as("Service classes should only use Repository class(es) from the own package");
```

But then I repeat the package name `com.company.backend.user` 3 times *and* I need to define this rule for each of the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a predicate on dependencies and operate on that.

```
classes()
    .that()
    .areAnnotatedWith(Service.class)
    .should(ArchConditions.onlyHaveDependenciesWhere(RepositoryAccessesAreOnlyWithinPackage.PREDICATE));
```

The predicate checks whether the access target is a repository and if that is the case it will validate whether the target resides within the same package as the calling class:

```
private static class RepositoryAccessesAreOnlyWithinPackage
        extends DescribedPredicate<Dependency> {

    public static final DescribedPredicate<Dependency> PREDICATE = new RepositoryAccessesAreOnlyWithinPackage();

    public RepositoryAccessesAreOnlyWithinPackage() {
        super("repository accesses are only within the same package");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Dependency dependency) {
        if (isRepositoryAccess(dependency)) {
            return areClassesInTheSamePackage(dependency.getOriginClass(), dependency.getTargetClass());
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean isRepositoryAccess(Dependency dependency) {
        return dependency.getTargetClass().isAnnotatedWith(Repository.class);
    }

    private boolean areClassesInTheSamePackage(JavaClass originClass, JavaClass targetClass) {
        return originClass.getPackageName().equals(targetClass.getPackageName());
    }
}
```